# make latent vector with 2 methods, are they same?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

[image]

First method uses `numpy.random.normal` and the second one uses `from torch.distributions import MultivariateNormal, Normal, Independent, Uniform`
Are they the same? (their shapes are different but my point is whether the data is from the same distribution)

Comment: Is your question whether `numpy.random.normal` and `torch.distributions.Normal` are equivalent?